# On a remote ssh session in Ubuntu (local is a Mac OS computer), why do colors come on when I type "bash"?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, iterm

On my Mac, after sshing into a ubuntu 18.04 computer, using iTerm, after typing in

```
bash
```

I see the `ls` colors turn on. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because bash supports colors in it's output.

writing `bash` changes your terminal to `bash` from (I assume) `sh` ?

And it loads a bunch of files:

```sh
FILES
       /bin/bash
              The bash executable
       /etc/profile
              The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
       /etc/bash.bashrc
              The systemwide per-interactive-shell startup file
       /etc/bash.bash.logout
              The systemwide login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
       ~/.bash_profile
              The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
       ~/.bashrc
              The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
       ~/.bash_logout
              The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
       ~/.inputrc
              Individual readline initialization file
```

you can find this info if you write `man bash` in the terminal, and go near the very end of the manual.

One of those files has color support.
It is usually the file `~/.bashrc` which has this:

```sh
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
  test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
  alias ls='ls --color=auto'
  #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
  #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

  alias grep='grep --color=auto'
  alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
  alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```